# Processing records in database with application running in different nodes

Tags: distributed

I need to process 100K records from DB, process them and update the status of the record in DB. If application is running on multiple nodes, how to make sure that same record is not picked by multiple nodes for processing?

This process is triggered by a quartz scheduler that runs every hour and we do not have the flexibility to configure the scheduler on each node to run at different times.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various approaches and the following two come to my mind at the moment.

(1) Use DB row locks
Make your nodes place an exclusive DB row lock (select for update) on the record the node is about to process. If the node can place the lock, then the process is free to process the record. Otherwise, the node should try another record because some other node has locked the record and is currently processing the record. You should randomize the selection of unprocessed records to somewhat minimize the chances of multiple nodes competing to process identical records.

(2) Assign your nodes some IDs and make your nodes use these IDs to select disjunct records from the processed data set. For example, if you have 10 nodes, assign them IDs 0 to 9. Then split your unprocessed records into disjunct sets based on the record ID by applying some function that produces numbers 0 to 9. For example, you can use the MOD function. Your nodes will then select only those unprocessed records whose ID is equal to the node ID. This is very simple to implement in SQL as long as you can assign some unique and consecutive IDs to your nodes.

If I were you, I would probably pick the second solution.

Comment: Thanks Jan Moravec. I like your approach-2. Worst case scenario - if one of the nodes die for long time. how to make this record picked by the other nodes?

Comment: In that case, you will have to introduce some kind of inter-node communication that allows individual nodes to determine how many active nodes exist and based on the current number of active nodes, individual nodes will have to pick different IDs. The algorithm that determines the new ID can be based on the node start time, i.e. you will sort all active nodes by their start time and assign new IDs that reflect the order. Do not ask me what to do when two nodes start at the exact same time. It is quite safe to assume they never do, unless you are implementing SW for a space shuttle etc.

Comment: You may want to look into existing and robust frameworks, such as Hadoop that can be used to process large data sets while leveraging distributed resources (multiple nodes).

Comment: Thanks Jan Moravec for sharing your thoughts.